# What is the relation between Dr. Kureha and Gol D. Roger?

Tags: one-piece

On Drum Island, after Chopper joined Mugiwara's crew, and they left, Dr. Kureha fired sakura powder (I forgot the name of this powder) that Dr. Hiluluk created as a farewell present for Chopper.

At that time, there's some conversation between Dr. Kureha and Dalton. Dr. Kureha asked Dalton if he knew about Gol D. Roger.

It seems that Dr. Kureha knew Gol D. Roger, but how did she know about him? What is the relation between Dr. Kureha and Gol D. Roger?

I don't remember if this is ever explained in the anime or manga.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Roger had visited Kureha to cure his illness before he went to Crocus. Or Roger might have just saved her village/island back on his voyages.

I am not so sure about their relation is, but they're definitely not enemies since Kureha smiled when stating [*D still lives*](http://www.mangareader.net/one-piece/154/8),

[image: Kureha recognizes Will of D]

Which telling us that she knows about *Will of D* and I am sure that in OP world, people who really know about it are always related to Roger.

Comment: Please support your answer with links to other sites. We are looking for factual answers rather than opinion based ones. Opinions should be put in comments. Thanks :3

Comment: I will edit and add sources later. I'd get fired if I get the sources now.

Comment: lol, you're in workplace when answering this? I'll wait about the source then

Comment: I am being an active member of SE society while I am bored at work :). I am figuring the chapter where Chopper just left Kureha and Dalton showed Luffy wanted poster. Looks like I gotta browse it later.